# La semaine et la diplomatie « people » ?

Tags: vocabulaire, anglais, emprunts, connotation, appositions

J'ai lu qu'à l'Élysée on avait accueilli récemment lors de différentes rencontres les porte-paroles et célébrités Bono et Rihanna, non pas pour un concert mais bien en effet pour discuter d'aide au développement. L'[article](http://www.lapresse.ca/arts/vie-de-stars/201707/26/01-5119436-rihanna-recue-a-lelysee.php) de l'*Agence France-Presse* mentionne ce qui suit ainsi qu'un [micromessage](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=26502418) d'une plateforme de microblogue dont voici aussi un extrait :

> C'est une semaine «*people*» pour Brigitte et Emmanuel Macron
>   [...]
>  « Diplomatie *people* avec Bono ou Rihanna et [...] »

C'est en italiques dans l'article et dans le message également. *Larousse* en ligne a le [nom](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/people/10910431?q=people#801266) sans référence à l'emprunt, pour « les célébrités, en particulier du monde du spectacle », mais aussi l'adjectif, sans définition, de l'[anglais](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/people/601199?q=people%3B) [*people*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/people?s=t) dans des [locutions](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/people/10910430/locution430?q=people#801097) comme *magazine/presse people*, pour « populaire, à sensation ». On ne sait pas s'il s'agit de deux emprunts distincts ([1](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8353357), [2](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8353362)) dont un serait entièrement lexicalisé ou en usage, ou si l'un aurait une connotation distincte de l'autre, et aucun marquage syntaxique ne permet de le dire (il y a qualification par *apposition* a priori).

---

- L'emploi des guillemets en plus des italiques sert-il a préciser
  l'acception du mot en évacuant la possibilité de la locution et la
  connotation que pourrait avoir « populaire, à sensation » dans un tel
  contexte ? L'absence de guillemets dans le deuxième exemple
  opère-t-elle l'effet contraire ou est-ce un acception différente (on
  note que le deuxième exemple est une critique des évènements par un
  politique naturellement opposé) ?
- En quoi *semaine mondaine, remplie d'activités sociales* diffère de
  semaine « people », peut-on expliquer à quoi sert l'emprunt *people*, ce qu'il préciserait ? Incidemment rencontrer
  des portes-paroles d'organisations non-gouvernementales qui sont des vedettes constitue-t-il une *mondanité* ou un truc *people* ? Un autre terme que *people* peut-il qualifier *semaine* ou *diplomatie* ici ; l'emploi d'une préposition ou un tour plus élaboré est-il requis ?
- L'adjectif *mondain* ou celui qu'on aurait sélectionné précédemment a-t-il une [connotation](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/mondanit%C3%A9/52174/synonyme) différente (inverse) de celle de *people* ?

Comment: N'oublions pas le suranné [_demi-mondaine_](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demi-mondaine).

Comment: C'est pas le cas, mais si "**P**eople" etait en magiscule, je dirais peut-etre  qu'il y a un lien avec l'hebdo [*People*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/People_(magazine)) (ou au moins avec l'espece de ["Beautiful People"](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/beautiful-people) qui se trouvent sur sa couverture)

Comment: @PapaPoule Le GDT spécule en effet sur ce lien (le magazine) comme influence (voir lien 1 ou 2). La question n'explore pas l'origine de l'emprunt et ses référents mais c'est bien intéressant, et ça peut servir à expliquer ce que le mot précise comparativement à d'autres adjectifs etc. Aussi je pense sans l'affirmer que la sémantique du mot en anglais ne contient pas le sens de _célébrités_ et donc le résultat est différent. Ce que contient l'ensemble _people_ semble avoir été façonné par une source ou une catégorie de sources, p.-ê selon leur publication en Fr. à un moment donné. Merci !

Comment: Le Tweet relève de la volonté de son auteur, qui n'a pas cru nécessaire/souhaitable d'italiser. L'auteur de l'Agence France-Presse, par contre, a italisé le mot dans sa citation du texte, ce qui révèle partiellement son opinion (ou celle de l'agence qui l'emploie) quant à l'utilisation de ce mot dans un discours français. Y ajouter des guillemets serait sans doute trop d'appropriation, mais dans leur propre utilisation du terme, elles furent utilisées. Votre question comparerait-elle plus une divergence de points de vue qu'une volonté de nuance?

Comment: @Feelew Merci, je pense que la combinaison guillemets et italiques m'a fortement impressionné, peut-être que je devrais en lire davantage à ce sujet. En comparant j'espère découvrir qqc. de plus sur l'emploi mais c'est possible qu'en ce qui concerne cette partie de la question qu'on puisse voir ça comme une nuance qui n'est pas significative, une nuance de style ou je ne sais trop...

Comment: Les guillemets, de simples signes typographiques, ont éventuellement intégré le discours oral, grâce à un signe commun utilisant [l'index et le majeur des deux mains](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8LBWKw9XWVE), sur lequel Wikipédia demeure étrangement silencieux. Ce signe aurait-il provoqué un nouveau type d'utilisation, marquant l'ironie, des guillemets à l'écrit? Wikipédia, du moins, [mentionne la valeur ironique possible des guillemets](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guillemet#Guillemets_d.E2.80.99ironie), à défaut de l'origine de cette utilisation. Y aurait-il un peu de ça ici?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> L'emploi des guillemets en plus des italiques sert-il a préciser l'acception du mot en évacuant la possibilité de la locution et la connotation que pourrait avoir « populaire, à sensation » dans un tel contexte ?

Les guillemets atténuent un peu le coté négatif de *people*.

> L'absence de guillemets dans le deuxième exemple opère-t-elle l'effet contraire ou est-ce un acception différente (on note que le deuxième exemple est une critique des événements par un politique naturellement opposé) ?

Oui, on peut analyser l'absence de guillemets de cette façon.

> En quoi semaine mondaine, remplie d'activités sociales diffère de semaine « people », peut-on expliquer à quoi sert l'emprunt people, ce qu'il préciserait ?

L'adjectif « mondaine » tend à s'appliquer à ce qui a trait aux gens « de la haute société » (aristocratie, haute bourgeoisie), plus tellement aux vedettes du spectacle.

> Incidemment rencontrer des portes-paroles d'organisations non-gouvernementales qui sont des vedettes constitue-t-il une mondanité ou un truc people ?

Ce n'est pas nécessairement une mondanité, encore qu'une réception au palais de l'Élysée, avec le protocole qui y est associé est quand même empreint de mondanité mais c'est le lieu qui est mondain, pas la semaine en question.

> Un autre terme que people peut-il qualifier semaine ou diplomatie ici ; l'emploi d'une préposition ou un tour plus élaboré est-il requis ?

*People* est bien adapté ici.

> L'adjectif mondain ou celui qu'on aurait sélectionné précédemment a-t-il une connotation différente (inverse) de celle de people ?

Oui. L'adjectif « mondain » est moins courant et s'applique plutôt aujourd'hui au cérémonial alors que *people*, dans son acception française, est de plus en plus utilisé depuis une vingtaine d'années pour désigner des personnes dont le nom, les photos, la vie apparaissent de façon récurrente dans la presse ou à la télévision, pas seulement les vedettes du monde du spectacle, mais aussi des politiques, des chefs d'entreprise, sportifs, créateurs, miss, journalistes et bien sûr aussi des têtes couronnées. Célébrités est le synonyme le plus proche que l'on pourrait trouver mais il lui manque ce petit coté futile que *people* véhicule.

Answer (score 5):

Selon moi, *people* fait référence aux célébrités de l'industrie du divertissement, qui vont des protagonistes de téléréalité aux têtes couronnées de la vieille Europe.

Mondain fait référence aux activités sociales des catégories socio-professionnelles supérieures, qui incluent mais ne sont pas limitées au milieu du divertissement.

Par exemple, quand la chanteuse Steph' de Monac' est prise pour cible des paparazzi, c'est du *people*. Quand la Princesse de Monaco ouvre le festival international du cirque, c'est du mondain.

Answer (score 1):

L'utilisation de l'italique est classiquement utilisée pour marquer l'utilisation de mots d'une langue étrangère.
L'utilisation des guillemets est à la charge de celui qui écrit.
S'il veut à la fois citer une personne et marquer l'utilisation d'un mot étranger, il ne me semble pas anormal d'écrire *«people»* comme dans votre première phrase. Les guillemets ne devraient peut-être pas être en italique. :)

Dans le cas d'une citation comme dans votre 2ème phrase, je ne suis pas choqué puisque la règle de l'italique est respectée.

Les mots "mondain" et "*people*" peuvent être utilisés comme adjectifs. Entre :
*semaine mondaine à la plage* et *semaine « people » à la plage*, il y a les paparazzi :). Les *people* ce sont les gens qu'on voit à la TV ou dans les média, qui sont en vogue. Le mot *mondain* fait référence à la bourgeoisie ou une sorte de.